# How to assign a ForeignKey field when a new instance is created

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a comment system and trying to implement voting. So on the line `comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, author=str(request.user), destination=id)` where I create a new Comment object, I want to add an upvotes field. So `upvotes=0` when the object is created. How do I do this?

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    destination = models.CharField(default='1', max_length=12, blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    comment_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_text


class CommentScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='score')
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.comment)
```

**views.py**

```
comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id)
score = CommentScore.objects.all()

if request.is_ajax():
    if comment.is_valid():
        comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, author=str(request.user), destination=id)
        print(comment)
        comment.save()
        username = str(request.user)
        return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment, 'text_length': comment_length, 'username': username})
    else:
        print(comment.errors)

context = {
    'score': score,
    'comment_list': comment_list,
}

return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

Comment: The `upvotes` field is already at the `CommentScore` model. What do you mean by "add an upvotes field"?

Comment: I was told to make a seperate model for voting because it will cause people to vote for a comment multiple times and to police how many times a person votes. So I did that, and now I'm trying to merge the two models. So when a `Comment` is created, I want to add `ForeignKey` from `CommentScore` to add an `upvotes=0` field, as well knowing who upvoted the post with the `user` field in `CommentScore`. Any idea?

Comment: The "up votes" and "down votes"  would occur after a comment object has already been created. Therefore, once a comment is made and another user then gets to the object and selects up vote or down vote your front end would have to call the backend to create a CommentScore object using the key for the Comment object.

Comment: Zorgan, you've had two good answers, please upvote and accept if they solve your question.

Comment: I've upvoted them both, I'm going to go through them and see which one works best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is essentially create a new `CommentScore` object and then map it to your `Comment`. This can be achieved like so.

```
comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id)
score = CommentScore.objects.all()

if request.is_ajax():
    if comment.is_valid():
        comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, author=str(request.user), destination=id)
        print(comment)
        comment.save()
        # This line creates a CommentScore model which maps to your Comment model
        com_score = CommentScore.objects.create(comment=comment)
        com_score.save()
        username = str(request.user)
        return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment, 'text_length': comment_length, 'username': username})
    else:
        print(comment.errors)

context = {
    'score': score,
    'comment_list': comment_list,
}

return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

Comment: This looks good so I'm going through this now and trying to make it work. So if I do `com_score = CommentScore.objects.create(comment=comment, upvotes=0)`. How do I then show each comment's number of upvotes in template? (I've pasted my current template in my edit)

Answer (score 2):

The "up votes" and "down votes" would occur after a comment object has already been created. Therefore, once a comment is made and another user then gets to the object and selects up vote or down vote your front end would have to call the backend to create a CommentScore object using the key for the Comment object. Essentially what will happen is this:

```
Comment (object) <- CommentScore (object) 
              ^- CommentScore (object)
```

You'll have many CommentScore objects linked to the Comment object. Each CommentScore object will record which user was the one that upvoted (upvote=1, downvote=0) or downvoted (upvote=0, downvote=1).
This setup will make it pretty easy to then query and get the sum of upvotes or downvotes for all CommentScore objects linked to the Comment object.

Here's an example from the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

In your case Reporter is Comment and Article is CommentScore.

Create a few Reporters:

> `r = Reporter(first_name='John', last_name='Smith', email='john@example.com')`
>
> `r.save()`
>
> `r2 = Reporter(first_name='Paul', last_name='Jones', email='paul@example.com')`
>
> `r2.save()`

Create an Article:

> from datetime import date
>
> `a = Article(id=None, headline="This is a test", pub_date=date(2005, 7, 27), reporter=r)`
>
> `a.save()`
>
> `a.reporter.id`
>
> `1`
>
> `a.reporter`
>
> `<Reporter: John Smith>`

In this example you can then get all the articles a reporter has written:

> `Article.objects.filter(reporter__first_name='John')`
>
> `<QuerySet [<Article: John's second story>, <Article: This is a test>]>`

Here's a more specific example for your case:

```
>>>  from testapp.models import Comment, CommentScore

# Creates one Comment object with pk=1
>>>  Comment.objects.create() 
<Comment: >

# Create 3 ComentScore objects that are associated with the first Comment I create
 CommentScore.objects.create(comment=Comment.objects.get(pk=1))
<CommentScore: >

>>>  CommentScore.objects.create(comment=Comment.objects.get(pk=1))
<CommentScore: >

>>>  CommentScore.objects.create(comment=Comment.objects.get(pk=1))
<CommentScore: >

# Now get the original Comment object that I created in my first step
>>>  cob = Comment.objects.get(pk=1)
>>>  cob.score
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager object at 0x107d67320>

# Grab all the CommentScore objects associated to that comment
 cob.score.all()
<QuerySet [<CommentScore: >, <CommentScore: >, <CommentScore: >]>

# Print upvote for each CommentScore object that's associated to that Comment I created
>>>  for ob in cob.score.all():
...      print(ob.upvotes)
...  
0
0
0
```

Comment: In my opinion, OP's question deals with _creation_ of `CommentScore`, as opposed to _retrieval_ which is what you demonstrated.

Comment: Creation is shown as an example above, i.e. Article -> CommentScore

Comment: So sorry, just noticed that. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks I went through that example and it's very helpful. But how would I show the `upvotes` associated with each unique `comment`? CommentScore.comment.author can fetch me the `author` field from my Comment model. But what about the other way around which is what i'm trying to achieve? Which is get the upvotes associated with each comment. Or should I do it the other way around so Article acts like Comment and Reporter acts like CommentScore. So then I can do Comment.score.upvotes?

Comment: No, you don't need to do it the other way around. Here's an example:
`CommentObject = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id)

Comment: Sorry, updating the answer with your specific case.

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions. And remember to mark my answer as the best answer.